# Cognos Report Studio: DMB-ECB-0088 A DMB cube build limit has been exceeded

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I'm running a report (Snapshot attached).
If I filter the dates range for 1-6 months it went well. But if I filter it for a year the report throws an error. DMB-ECB-0088 A DMB cube build limit has been exceeded.

I searched over for this error, and find nothing constructive. User requirement is for a year or two. And I was confident that simple report can handle huge data. Its not an Active report.

Already Tried:
I've tried turning on the Local Cache.
And also changed the MaxCacheSize value to 1200 from default 400 in qfs_config.xml file.

I'm not sure if its an issue at DB's end. My DWH source is DB2.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Nuh

[image]

Comment: Modifying parameters in that file is the only thing I know of.  You might also increase `MaxNumberOfMembers` and `MaxNumberOfRecordRows`. In theory you can continue to bump those up until your report runs, but you may just replace the current error with out of memory errors.  How many rows is your query returning?  Are you sure it is aggregating as much as possible on the database?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I also tried that (increased those parameters by placing a zero(0) at the end) But still the same error.
How can I see the number of rows returning? I haven't been successful in running that report for a year filter.
As for the aggregation, no there are really few aggregations at report end.

Comment: I got the same error, when created a dimentional report against relational datasource. Is it your case? Basically you need to use as many filteres as early as possible to minimize number of rows sent from DB to Cognos. This error happens when Cognos starts local processing, i.e. processing on Report Server.